# Remove component name from url in joomla2.5

Tags: joomla

i want remove component name from url

http://mydomain.in/tfn/index.php/en/component/users/profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a menu link. The component name is only there because you cannot be sure that there is not an article etc that has the name profile so it adds segments to the url to ensure the url will be unique. The menu system will guarantee uniqueness. You do not have to display the menu, just make a menu that you never show the module for for anything like this.